# Will running a script using grep / awk on a log file ever impact the Application writing to the log file?

Tags: awk, scripting, grep

I have used scripts to monitor and extract data from log files for years and never questioned the basic toolset that most people take for granted. In particular *grep* and *awk* are used by almost everyone in the community.

I found the current grep bugs (some back dating a few years):
http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=grep

And from the man pages for GNU grep 2.6.3:

> Known Bugs
>
> Large repetition counts in the {n,m} construct may cause grep to use  lots  of  memory.   In  addition,  certain  other  obscure  regular expressions require exponential time and space, and may cause grep to run out of memory.
>
> Back-references are very slow, and may require exponential time.

And the man pages for GNU Awk 3.1.7:

> BUGS
>
> The -F option is not necessary given the command line variable assignment feature; it remains only for backwards compatibility.
>
> Syntactically invalid single character programs tend to overflow the parse stack, generating a rather unhelpful message.  Such programs are surprisingly difficult to diagnose in the completely general case, and the effort to do so really is not worth it.

I was interested in the limitations for example

- when using complex regex,
- extremely large files that are not rotated,
- logs that are written to thousands of times per hundredths of a second

Would it just be a case of monitoring the memory usage of the script to make sure it is not using massive amounts of memory?

Is it good practice to implement a timeout feature for scripts that might possibly take a long time to execute?

Are there other good standards and structures that people also use when building solutions using these tools?

I found the extremely helpful answer for the equivalent findstr to give me a better understanding of scripting in a Windows environment:
[What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: I would use `ulimit` to constrain the monitoring scripts (memory, CPU time...). Did you consider this option?

Answer (score 0):

The awk/grep commands are both reading the log file in read-only mode, so there is no impact on the log file getting corrupted because of simultaneous access by both application (write mode) and awk/grep programs (read-only mode).

There is definitely a CPU, memory usage by the awk/grep programs which can impact the application writing to the log file. This impact is similar to any other process using the system resources. The grep/awk command are no exceptions. Depending on what the grep/awk scripts are doing, they can consume a lot of CPU/RAM. A badly written code in any language can cause problems. As suggest in the comments, it is good to constraint the monitoring processes. `ulimit` and `cgroups` are the option available for constraining the resources. Other good option is to use `timeout` which kill the script if it is taking more than expected time.